# .addClass() not working in JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

I have numerous websites that are on a "dev" site meaning that it is dummy data and not all functionality works.  What happens is that I have this function in my document.ready() that is supposed to find the html for the popup box and add a class to it, which gives the popup box a little blue header bar.
Function:

```
$("document").ready(
function(){
    //loadSummary();
    NOT_AVAILABLE_ALERT = $("#modalMessageAlert").dialog(
            {
                position: "center",
                resizable: false,
                bgiframe: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 250,
                height: 200,
                draggable: false,
                modal: true,
                close:function(event,ui){
                    },
                open:function(event,ui){
                    }
            });
   modifyModalHeader("modalMessageAlert","demo_dialog_header");
}
);

function modifyModalHeader(id,className){
var refs = $("#"+id).prev();
var ref = refs.eq(0);
ref.addClass(className);
}

function navigateDemo() {
NOT_AVAILABLE_ALERT.dialog("open");
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="tempXML" ></div>
<div id="modalMessageAlert"style="left:-200px; display:none">
    <h3>This feature is not available in this demo household.</h3>
    <input style="margin-bottom: 15px" type="button" Value="Close" onclick="NOT_AVAILABLE_ALERT.dialog('close');"/>
</div>
```

HTML link:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="javascript:navigateDemo();return false;" value="Save" id="save"/>
```

CSS

```
#modalMessageAlert {
background-color:#fff;
cursor:pointer;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.demo_dialog_header {
background-image:url(/backoffice/Prospects/APP360/images/demo_modal_header.gif)
}
```

If i understand correctly the modifyModalHeader function is supposed to find the tempXML div using the .prev() functionality and add that class to the tempXML div, and then when a user clicks the "submit" aka save button it shows the dialog, the dialog shows fine, just without the referenced image as the background-image, which just creates a solid blue line across the top about 15px wide.  This EXACT same functionality and references work on pages included in the same directories just fine, but for some reason i can't get this to load correctly.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
-NickG

Comment: So what you're basically saying is that the image does'nt exists in the folder / filename you specified, and that you should change the path to a valid file, because the first thing you obviously did was to open the console, and see that the class was actually added ?

Comment: the image exists and is referenced correctly, like i said the same exact function calls on other pages located in the same directory work perfectly and reference the same file.  When I open the console there is no class added to the tempXML or modalMessageAlert div, not even on the pages where it displays correctly, which i didn't quite understand either. if you're really trying to help i appreciate it, but your comments read very condescendingly, im just looking for some help

Comment: Start by removing the quotes around "document", next change out the variable name className, as that is a reserved keyword in javascript, and see what that gets you ?

Comment: that didn't do it, is there a way for me to check if the class has been added, when i go into the debugger mode it goes through the document.ready() function fine and doesn't give any errors, and seems to append the classname to the <div> but doesn't display in the source code with the new class

Comment: The new class wont show up in "view source", but in modern browsers (and that's not IE) you can hit F12 and open the console, find the element and see if it has the class etc.

Comment: yea after using Chrome's Developer tools I can see the class is being added in the same way that it is being added on a page that the popup works correctly, they look identical, which is frustrating.  I think I might just have to re-write the function or just create a new popup window with the header bar hard-coded or referenced differently in it, this is just getting a little frustrating.  Thank you very much for your help and for your insight on developer tools!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that i had conflicting style sheets that were overriding the class because i used some JQuery calendar extenders and they were being referenced as ui-widgets as does that popup.